# How do I call localStorage to array values in php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have tried  to pass the values from javascript to PHP

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
const formData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formdata'));
const getthelocation = formData.getthelocation;`
</script>
```

PhP

```
<?php
$getLoc= ["<script>document.writeln(getthelocation );</script>"];
var_export ($getLoc);
```

Output

ARRAY ( 0 => 'ISTANBUL,TOKAT,BURSA,YALOVA ', )

But I'm Looking for

ARRAY ( 0 => 'ISTANBUL', 1 =>'TOKAT',  2 =>'BURSA', 3 =>'YALOVA')

Comment: PHP runs in the server. It generates text **and ONLY text** to be sent to the browser. The text that your PHP generates happens to be javascript source code but make no mistake, from the point of view of PHP it is still only text, not live objects. Now, after PHP sends that text (your javascript source code) to hour network card then to your router and then over the internet to the browser, the browser then executes that text/string as javascript and now that javascript runs. But remember, the javascript is running on a different machine than your PHP code

Comment: @slebetman is right but you are lucky you can inject the code into the dom (vs doing it right and making a JSON API endpoint to fetch the data) - https://3v4l.org/ciRlH

Comment: Okay, Thanks for quick response, without javascrpit it it possible that we get values from localStorage,  I need store data like this $loc = array( 'bursa','tokat','istanbul');

Answer (score 0):

Send your data from local storage in JS script, after this you can make with your data all you need: explode it by comma, make some value object, etc.

This will be the correct way.

Comment: I have tried this $getLoc= ["<script>document.writeln(test);</script>"]; $str_arr = explode (",", $getLoc); 
//print_r($str_arr);   But its not working

Comment: Your $getLoc is an array with one element inside.  
Try this:  
`$cities = explode (',', $getLoc[0] ?? '');`